# Emacs: scaling down shrinks faces, not line height

Tags: linux, emacs, emacs24

When I downsize text in emacs 24.3.1 (Ubuntu) e.g. via C-x C--, lines shrink only to about modeline height, while the text itself behaves as wanted. This also makes minimap unusable because the number of lines per screen stays constant, only adding white space. What could be the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this happen when you run Emacs with `emacs -Q`, preventing configuration file from loading?

Comment: Hi @Chris No, with `emacs -Q` it works as it should.  Ok, then I should wonder about my .emacs. It's > 1000 lines, so any suggestions about likely culprits? `font-lock-mode`? Explicit face customizations? I read about the `'line-height` property of the `'newline` symbol, but setting it to `t` as suggested by manual "37.11 Line Height" didn't have effect.

Comment: No idea. Do a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm): comment out half of your config and see if the problem goes away. That tells you which half of your config contains the problem code. Repeat until you've found the culprit.